# How can an electron's de Broglie wavelength be LONGER than .0024264 nanometers?

Tags: waves, electrons, wavelength, matter, microscopy

If the rest mass of an electron is about 510,998.5 ev, or .5109985 Mev, doesn't that mean that even the slowest-moving electron has a wavelength of no more than .0024264 nanons?

That is the wavelength I get when putting in an energy of 511 ev into energy-to-wavelength calculators....

Yet, I read that electrons in a vacuum tube might reach an energy such that their wavelength is reduced to .1 nm, or maybe .01 nm...

I am confused....

Answer (score 0):

Mass has an associated energy given by the Mass-Energy equivalence $E=mc^2$.But nevertheless it should be noted that this is a passive energy meaning its not available as Free Energy to do work.

de-Broglie Wavelength relates momentum(or Kinetic Energy) to matter wavelength. Now, mass equivalent energy cannot be used here because its NOT kinetic energy neither can it be spontaneously converted to the KE of electron.

Answer (score 0):

Mass equivalent energy or rest mass here can't be considered in calculation as it is not free to do work or can't be converted to kinetic energy while De-Broglie wavelength is associated with kinetic energy of the particle. This is the reason behind fallacy in your calculation.